# Optimal three parameter variable stabilizing transformation of a Poisson

Tags: variance, poisson-distribution, heteroscedasticity, count-data, variance-stabilizing

In the paper: ["On the classical choice of variance stabilizing transformations and an application for a Poisson variate"](https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/75.4.803), Shaul K. Bar-Lev and Peter Enis give an optimal two parameter variance stabilizing transformation of a Poisson random variable, where optimality (roughly) means that it ensures the variance is as close as possible to constant in the large mean limit.

The transformation is:
$$f_{\alpha,\beta}(x)= 2(x+2\alpha-\beta){(x+\alpha)}^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
and they give the optimal $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as $\alpha^*=\frac{3}{8}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}$ and $\beta^*=\frac{3}{8}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$, so the resulting transformation is given by:
$$f_{\alpha^*,\beta^*}(x)=\frac{24x+9+2\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{144x+54+24\sqrt{3}}}.$$

They show that if $X$ is a Poisson random variable with mean $\lambda$, then for general $\alpha$ and $\beta$:
$$\operatorname{var}{f_{\alpha,\beta}(X)}=1+O(\lambda^{-1})$$
as $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$. However:
$$\operatorname{var}{f_{\alpha^*,\beta^*}(X)}=1+O(\lambda^{-3})$$
as $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$. (This is the precise sense of optimality. The two optimally chosen parameters remove the two lead terms of the variance.)

They also suggest a three-parameter family of transformations, given by:
$$g_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}(x)= 2(x+2\alpha-\beta){(x+\alpha)}^{-\frac{1}{2}} - {(x+\gamma)}^{-\frac{3}{2}},$$
but they do not give the optimal $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ for this three-parameter family.

What are the optimal $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$? I.e., what are the $\alpha^\circ$, $\beta^\circ$ and $\gamma^\circ$ such that:

$$\operatorname{var}{g_{\alpha^\circ,\beta^\circ,\gamma^\circ}(X)}=1+O(\lambda^{-4})$$
as $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: "Optimal" in what sense, specifically?

Comment: The same sense as used in that paper! Minimizing the large mean departure of the variance of the transformed variable from 1/4. In the two-parameter case, they zero the terms on 1/mean and 1/mean^2. With three parameters, it should be possible to also zero the term on 1/mean^3.

Comment: The paper is behind a paywall, so it is incumbent upon you to explain what you mean.

Comment: @whuber I've edited the question to clarify.